# AngularJs - Route resolver chaining

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to delete the draft data and load original data whenever discardDraft is passsed in route using route resolver.

My use case is delete promise must be completed before going to getdata.

Delete and Get are runnning paralley. How to make them

```
resolve: {
   data: [
          '$route',
          '$q',
          'service1',
          function ($route, $q, service1) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var getDataPromise = service1.getData($route.current.params); 
            if ($route.current.params.deleteDraft) {
               var deleteDraftPromise = service1.deleteDraft($route.current.params.id);
               deleteDraftPromise.then(function () {
                     getDataPromise.then(function (resultData) {
                        deferred.resolve(resultData);
                     });
               });
            } 
            else {
                     getDataPromise.then(function (resultData) {
                           deferred.resolve(resultData);
                      });
                 }
            return deferred.promise;
            }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

try one after other to resolve

```
resolve: {
data: ['$route', '$q', 'service1', function ($route, $q, service1) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if ($route.current.params.deleteDraft) {
        service1.deleteDraft($route.current.params.id, function (res) {
            service1.getData($route.current.params, function (argument) {
                deferred.resolve(argument);
            });
        });
    } else {
        service1.getData($route.current.params, function (argument) {
            deferred.resolve(argument);
        });
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}]
```

}